# How can I add attachment to related list of object when the user is not logged in?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, attachment, fileupload

I have a Visualforce page with lwc components in Site, which does not require user to log in. Here the requirement is to upload a file as attachment to a Custom object. In other places we had login flow and there the api session id was used to upload files using sforce connection.js as apex was giving heap size issue. Is there any other way by which we can achieve the file upload where there is no user login involved?

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="formController">
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }    
        </style>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>
    </head>
    <apex:includeLightning />    
    <div id="LightningComponentid" />    
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:myFormApp", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:myForm",{ 
        },
          "LightningComponentid",
          function(cmp) {

          });
        },
    '{!SiteUrl}'
    );
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Is the file being uploaded from Lightning component?

Comment: @Mahmood Yes it is from lwc component

Comment: You need to put that code instead, because this vf page is only using lightning out to call the lightning component in it. There is no logic written here.

Comment: @Mahmood the lwc template contains a form with a input type file, on selection of file I want to upload that file to a record (the record Id I get from url). The challenge I am facing is there is no user login for this page and because of which there is no session id that I can use for uploading the file